# What's the correct way to implement a web service with the repository pattern

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, design-patterns

I'm about to start a project which will require a web site, connected to a web service. The web service will retrieve data from a database, and return it to the website.

My question is about how to properly separate business concerns with data access.

The service can be separated by utilizing the repository pattern. Then in the service calls implementations I can get the required data from the repository in the form of entities, then return it over the wire.

Similarly I can do the same on the website. Use the repository to hide the implementation details of getting the data from the service and serializing it into an entity or entities.

However, my main issue with this approach is that both the service and the website will both have definitions for their entities. Is there a pattern I can use that will allow me to define these entities once, or is this architecture way off from what is common / best practice.

I should mention that the technologies I'm using are asp.net with c# and I'm not using an entity framework.

Comment: So you can use frameworks such as MediatR which will allow you to create small units of code. So each one is easily unit testable. The thing to remember is don't get caught up in what are the best patterns etc, etc. Only introduce patterns when you need them. If you don't need `Repository` just use the `DbContext` (EntityFramework)

Comment: Each repository will be responsible for separating the business logic and data layer in their respective objects. For the service, it means that if I ever change the database technology, I can do that without affecting the objects the service sends. For the website, it means that if I ever need to change the service it connects to, all the business logic remains unchanged. It also means that I can unit test both projects easier as I'll be able to switch out the dependencies with mocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a WCF Data Service and a client for it in the very same solution. Visual Studio will enable to use the very same classes and model at client side what you define in the service side.

Bonus: In case you use the concept right, the IQueryable will can be marshalled to client side (not the result), so you can even do ad-hoc queries in client side, (supposing you repository's method returns with IQueryable) just the result will travel in the wire. This will be important for paging scenarios too.

Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668184(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: I haven't worked with WCF much, but afaik it is not necessary to define them in the same solution. If you are using the autogenerated proxy class feature and those entities are marked with the `[DataContract]`  attribute they can be autogenerated by consumer code at the same time as the proxy class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I've seen of MVC, it plays nicer with WebAPI, is the same functionality available in WebAPI?

Comment: @AdamDrew: Unfortunatelly I do not know WebAPI in that level I can answer this.

Comment: @AdamDrew you can obviously create them in the same solution and use the same domain objects. You will still have to worry about data serialization and deserialization (though WebAPI makes that easier on your service) and you won't get those `IQueryable` features.